# Errorbars with stacked histograms

Tags: gnuplot

I have plotted stacked histogram with error bars as follows, with column 6 representing error :

```
plot file1 using 2:xtic(1) fs pattern 1 fc 1 title col, \
    '' using ($3-$2):xtic(1) fs pattern 2 fc 3 title col, \
    '' using 0:3:6 with errorbars lw 2 lt -1
```

The plotted graph gets error bars beside the histogram rather than on top of it. How to get error bars on top of the blue histogram. Unfortunately, I was not allowed to post an image.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Following did the trick:

```
plot file1 using 2:xtic(1) fs pattern 1 fc 1 title col, \
    '' using ($3-$2):xtic(1) fs pattern 2 fc 3 title col, \
    '' using ($0-1):3:6 with errorbars lw 2 lt -1
```